# Can anyone point me to a reference where the following is explained?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, soft-question, set-theory

I have got the following line from the Wikipedia cantor set:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set

"It can also be shown that the Haar measure is an image of any probability, making the Cantor set a universal probability space in some ways."

Can anyone show or refer to material where it is explained?

Comment: This dlia.ir/Scientific/e_book/Science/Mathematics/QA_299.6_433..._/007781.pdf link has the term "universal probability space" and includes "cantor set" but I can't reach it, because of a "proxy loop". Other than that I didn't see anything too promising with the search term 'Haar measure any "universal probability space" cantor set'